# How to root the ZTE Z Max pro?

Tags: rooting

Im very new to this world of technology, i have the ZTE Z Max pro from meteo pcs and want it rooted. This phone sounds much harder to root compared to the stylo i had. I dont completely understand what TWRP and flashing is. Is there anybody thata willing to walk me through it, like android for a dummy? Lol

Comment: If you're that new to technology, then rooting might go against your interests, since the root user is able to alter almost anything on a device, to the point of making it useless.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are new to technology rooting might not be the best way to into technology especially with your zmax, which seems to be a bit more difficult to root. But if you really want to root your phone have a look at androidforums.com, e.g. [this discussion about rooting the zmax](http://androidforums.com/threads/zte-zmax-pro-z981-root-discussion.1055354/).